# Can you make rune words out of Wirt's Leg?

Tags: diablo-ii

I remember when I used to play Diablo II that I often find a socketed Wirt's Leg when obtaining it from Tristram. Could you make a rune word out of it? Or was it just socketed sometimes because it was considered a weapon? I'd find it out for myself, but I don't have the game anymore at the moment.

Comment: Nah you never could. Wirts Leg is a unique item and you can't make runewords from unique items.

Comment: I hate that I didn't consider that it was unique. I guess its been much too long since I played that great game

Comment: Heh yeah. I was just talking about D2 with a buddy of mine yesterday about how I put 1000 hours into this one.

Comment: @ChaseC: Wirt's leg is not a unique (gold) item; it is a quest item.  It is a quest item that comes in normal (white) and socketed (grey) forms naturally.  There are magic (blue) and rare (yellow) versions of it created from cube recipes or from imbuing.  In previous versions you could make rune words from it but no longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Diablo Wiki ([here](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Wirt%27s_Leg) and [here](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Rune_Words)), you can not put a rune word in Wirt's Leg.

I only remember picking up a single socket Wirt's Leg. It may be that you are only able to pick up a Wirt's Leg with 1 socket, making it impossible to create a rune word. It may be that the developers have removed the ability for rune words to 'activate' on the item. Since one of the requirements in activating runewords is its application on a specific weapon, I would say it is the later.

Comment: I've found Wirt's Leg with 2 sockets before. Can also drop with 3

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer possible to make a runeword in Wirt's Leg.  Wirt's Leg does drop in socketed versions (1, 2 or 3 sockets possible.)  In earlier versions (1.09, perhaps just 1.07) it was possible to make a runeword in Wirts Leg but not in the current version.